# How To Control FileWrite in Parallel For Loop in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, task-parallel-library

I have a method that is called from outer function in a loop.This method generates a list on every call and writes to a file. Pseudo Code goes below

```
Public Class MyClass
{

OuterMethod()
{
For(//n number of iteration){Call InnerMethod())}
}

InnerMethod()
{
var a = new List<Data>
for(//x number of iteration){
a.Add(data);
}
WriteToFile(a);

}
```

Now I want to limit the WriteToFile Call. I want to do in batches(say 500 and configurable). In this case I can declare the list at class level and pass the batch count in innetrmethod and checkforcount before writting and clear the list to regenerate the batch from next iteration of InnerMethod() call. This solves my problem when the loop is sequential.

Now, given the scenario where InnerMethod() is called as ParallelFor loop. In this case I won't have control over a thread who can do the count check and reset the list one at a time.

Please suggest a way so that I can make this filewrite as batch no matter the InnerMethod() is called via sequential for or parallelFor.

Comment: Are you familiar with thread synchronization? There are mechanisms available, like the `lock` statement, that prevents more than one threads from entering a protected region. When a second thread wants to enter the region, it must wait for the previously entered thread to exit from the region.

Comment: Writing files is almost always faster without using threads. Why do you want to use threads?